# Hiding html element clicked after ajax success

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I'm new to Web Development and making a mock twitter application. I want the tweet box to be removed after I click on the delete button (only if it is actually deleted in the backend)

I'm using django templating to loop through each tweet:

```
{% for tweet in data%}

<div class="container border border-primary rounded">
    <p> tweet: {{tweet.content}}</p>
    <div class="row">
        {{tweet.id}}
        <p class = "likes" style="margin: 0px 10px;"> likes: {{tweet.likes}} </p>
        <button class="btn btn-dark like" style="margin: 0px 10px;">like</button>
        <p class = "retweets" style="margin: 0px 10px;" > retweets: {{tweet.retweets}}</p>
        <button class = "btn btn-dark retweet" style="margin: 0px 10px;">retweet</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark float-right delete_tweet" onclick="delete_tweet('{{tweet.id}}')">delete</button>
    </div>
     
</div>
 
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the `delete_tweet` function:

```
function delete_tweet(id){
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'deleteTweet'%}",
            data: {'id':id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This deletes the tweet in the backend fine, but the `remove` method doesn't work -
I'm pretty sure that I'm `this` is not referring to the right scope, what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `.closest(".your-element-name").remove();`

Your Button

```
function delete_tweet(id, that){

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'deleteTweet'%}",
        data: {'id':id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $(that).closest(".rounded").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: The problem is the use of `this` inside the success function, lot's of answers to similar questions said the same thing, but I can't adapt them to my specific case

Comment: use this with that method

Comment: could you explain what `that` is?